# How can I store my JWT Token in my state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt

userAction.js -> Frontend, Action

```
export const login = (userID, password) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST });
       
        const url = "http://localhost:8080/authenticate/";
        const config = {
          auth: {
            username: userID,
            password,

          },
        };
    
        const data = {};
        const response = await axios.post(
            url, 
            data, 
            config,
            
        )

        dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: config});
        
 
        if (response.status === 200) {
          // Login succeeded
          const token = response.data.token;
          console.log("TOKEN\n" + token);
          config.token = response.data.token;
          console.log(response.data.token);
          
        }
        
        localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(config) );
    }
```

My login function in REST Server :

```
exports.login = async (req,res) =>{

  const b64auth = (req.headers.authorization || '').split(' ')[1] || '';
  const [userID, password] = Buffer.from(b64auth, 'base64').toString().split(':');
  const user = await User.findOne({ userID: userID });
  if(!user) return res.status(400).send('User not found');
  const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
  if(!validPass) return res.status(400).send('Incorrect Password');

  //const token = generateToken(user.userID);
  let payload = {
    userID: user.userID
  }
  const token = generateToken(userID);
  
  res.header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token).json(token);
  console.log(user);
  return res.json({token});
}
```

I generate my token this way :

```
const generateToken = (_id, userID) => {
  console.log('Signing token for ID ', _id);
  console.log('Secret key is ', process.env.JWT_KEY);
  const token = jwt.sign({ _id, userID}, process.env.JWT_KEY, {
    expiresIn: "30d",
  });
  console.log('Signed token: ', token);
  return token;
};
```

I try to store my token in my "userInfo" State .. but only username and password is displayed not token ..It works before .. but I don´t know why it´s not working anymore ^^ I´m completely at a loss

I hope someone sees the error

my Console gives me the detail:

```
TOKEN 
undefined
```

Comment: `jwt.sign((generateToken({userID}),payload), SECRET_KEY);` why are you calling `jwt.sign` on  `generateToken` ? generateToken already signs it...

Comment: I don´t know .. I tried something .. I can delete it

Comment: `//return res.json({token});` uncomment this

Comment: Unfortunately it still didn't work: / @whygee

Answer (score 0):

Return the token with the token key at the end of your login function in the REST API, since that's how you access it in your frontend.

```js
return res.status(200).json({token: token});
```

Comment: I get the error : Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client if I type this in my login funtion in rest api

Comment: Try removing `.json(token)` from the end of the line starting with the `res.header` call. Also, the code I wrote should be at the end of the login function, replacing the current version of `return res.json({token});` with the one in the answer.

Comment: You can't do `res.header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token).json(token);` and `res.status(200).json({token: token})` at the same time

Comment: Yes thats right.. it has something to do with my userAction.js .. I think @whygee

Comment: Try the solution I wrote in my comment above. If you are uncertain, you can always just debug the response in your frontend. (response.data specifically). But I'm fairly sure what I wrote fixes the issue.

Comment: It doesn´t fix @norbot thats the problem ..

Comment: Could you show the updated code?

Comment: I have edit it directly .. here  @norbot